# modified suspend mode for ubuntu

Tags: networking, power-management, suspend, vlc, streaming

Is it possible to put ubuntu (12.04) into a 'modified suspend' mode which basically works like the regular suspend, but allows me to run my vlc for streaming video through the network, while I am away from home/overnight? I would like to minimize power consumption to absolute minimum during these periods, while maintaining this specific functionality.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't sound anything like a S1/S3 suspend... But you have a few options to help with power consumption:

1. Just optimise the running system by playing around with tools like `powertop`. This is likely only going to make a difference of a few Watts, if that.
2. Investigate [Wake On Lan](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WakeOnLan). This means you'll have to ping the computer to wake it up before you can use it, and you might be able to script it to make it work seamlessly, but more often than not it makes it slightly harder to use.
3. Move your media to a lower-powered NAS and just shut your computer down (or do a proper suspend). Costs more initially but if your computer is a beasty, it'll cut down on the bills.

Comment: thanks for the detailed response...the Wake On Lan seems to be the best option, since I don't have another computer. My BIOS supports Wake On Lan, but not Wake on Wireless, but does that mean that using this option would require a physical cable connection to the router for it to work?